# Is there a solution for this network request denied when using appwrite to create a web app

Tags: reactjs, appwrite

how to clear this error

> (Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1/account'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Register.tsx:68 AppwriteException: Network request failed at
> Client.eval
> (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/appwrite/dist/esm/sdk.js:423:23)
> at Generator.throw () at rejected
> (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/appwrite/dist/esm/sdk.js:42:65)
> user.tsx:34 POST https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1/account net::ERR_FAILED
> 404 (Not Found))

corrected some mistakes and even though of commenting the later code

Comment: Your server should accept requests from origin localhost:3000. If you own the server, do changes there for this and check.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your project on Appwrite, you must register your application by adding it as a web app in the Appwrite console. You can achieve this by clicking on **Web** in the **Add a platform** section.

(In your case, the hostname added there will be `localhost`)

[image: Appwrite Console]

This is necessary to authorize your application (the request origin) to communicate with Appwrite.

Answer (score 1):

You just add in hostname only an asterisk `*`. Then after one minute your CORS problem is solved.

[image]